# Call to undefined method League\Flysystem\Filesystem::getDriver() Al utilizar Dropbox en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, storage

Lo que trato de hacer es utilizar dropbox como disco para subir imágenes a la nube y poder cargarlas desde allí.
El tutorial que estoy siguiendo es este https://styde.net/subir-y-manejar-archivos-con-laravel-en-dropbox/ y la documentacion en Laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#driver-prerequisites pero al iniciar me lanza el siguiente error:

Call to undefined method League\Flysystem\Filesystem::getDriver()

El error es al lanzar el construct del controller el cual está de esta manera:

```
use App\Models\File;
use Spatie\Dropbox\Client;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class FileController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->dropbox = Storage::disk('dropbox')->getDriver()->getAdapter()->getClient();
        
    }
```

En filesystems.php está así:

```
'dropbox' => [
            'driver' => 'dropbox',
            'authorizationToken' => env('DROPBOX_TOKEN')
        ],
```

Y en el provider se encuentra así:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use League\Flysystem\Filesystem;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Spatie\Dropbox\Client as DropboxClient;
use Spatie\FlysystemDropbox\DropboxAdapter;

class DropboxServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    
    public function boot()
    {
        Storage::extend('dropbox', function ($app, $config) {
            $client = new DropboxClient(
                $config['authorizationToken']
            );
 
            return new Filesystem(new DropboxAdapter($client));
        });
    }
```

He visto muchos ejemplos pero no logro descubrir cual sea el error.

Comment: Qué versión de Laravel utilizas?

Comment: Uso Laravel 9.18.0 y php 8.0.13

Comment: En ese caso... has probado con el ejemplo de https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#custom-filesystems? Tiene algunas diferencias con el tuyo